# Exclude null properties when converting JAXB annotated PoJo to Json when the JAXBElement value is null

Tags: java, json, jackson, jaxb

I'm using Jackson to write a Jaxb annotated Pojo to Json. The input is an XML document which I read into the Pojo and then write it out as Json.
It's been working great and has also been performant for large documents (using a Streaming SAX parser).

I'm hitting an issue when the XML has

`<ns1:SomeElement xsi:nil="true"/>`

The JAXBElement representing this property correctly unmarshalls to an object with

```
value = null
nil = true
```

When writing my Pojo out to Json, I have the requirement to NOT HAVE `"someElement": null` in the JSON. I'm absolutely ok if the output Json excludes "someElement" altogether.

**Writing to Json:**

1. I'm using a mixin to write the value of the JAXBElement
2. Setting the objectMapper to exclude null (but this is not working)

   ```
   objectMapperForXml = new ObjectMapper();
   objectMapperForXml.addMixIn(JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixin.class);
   objectMapperForXml.setVisibility(objectMapperForXml.getSerializationConfig()
           .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
           .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
           .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
           .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
           .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
   objectMapperForXml.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
   /* I've tried NON_NULL, NON_EMTY as well */
   JsonNode document = objectMapperForXml.valueToTree(item.getTransformedDocument());

   /* a mixin annotation that overrides the handling for the JAXBElement */
   public interface JAXBElementMixin {
       @JsonValue
       Object getValue();
   }
   ```

Despite this, my output json contains: `"someElement":null`

What am I missing ?

Wondering if there is an issue with the NOT_NULL handling considering the JAXBElement encapsulated property is technically != null ? If so, is there another way to exclude the nulls ?

(The other angle for me to explore is to figure out how to generate the Json schema that validates the above generated json while not crapping out due to null...Basically it needs to have

```
"anyOf": [
      {"type": "string"},
      {"type": "null"}
    ]
```

but again, haven't been able to coax the following code to generate the json schema this way

```
public static void main(final String[] arguments)
{
    final JsonGenerationFromJaxbClasses instance = new JsonGenerationFromJaxbClasses();
    final SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = instance.createJaxbObjectMapper();
    mapper.addMixIn(JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixin.class);

    mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
            .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
    try {
        for (SchemaMapping mapping : SchemaMapping.values()) {
            mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(mapper.constructType(Class.forName(mapping.fullyQualifiedClassName)), visitor);
            final com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mapping.name() + ".schema"));
            writer.write(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create instance of ObjectMapper with JAXB introspector
 * and default type factory.
 *
 * @return Instance of ObjectMapper with JAXB introspector
 *    and default type factory.
 */
private ObjectMapper createJaxbObjectMapper()
{
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
    final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);
    // make deserializer use JAXB annotations (only)
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);
    return mapper;
}

/**
 * Write out JSON Schema based upon Java source code in
 * class whose fully qualified package and class name have
 * been provided.
 *
 * @param fullyQualifiedClassName Name of Java class upon
 *    which JSON Schema will be extracted.
 */

private void writeToStandardOutputWithModuleJsonSchema(
        final String fullyQualifiedClassName)
{
    final SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try
    {
        mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(mapper.constructType(Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName)), visitor);
        final com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
        out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
    }
    catch (Exception cnfEx) {
        cnfEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) in your POJO class.
You may add it at class level or field level.

Comment: @Santos unfortunately that's not an option since the POJO's are generated and quite huge

Comment: Just tried it though, didn't work. :-(

Comment: I think that some configurations that you put override the others.  Below serialization config should remove the null values, or at least will return empty array like {}.        objectMapperForXml.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

Comment: objectMapperForXml.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL); is what I had before encountering this issue. It definitely looks like a bug related to the fact that the JaxBElement not being null (eventhough the encapsulated value is null) trips up the NON_NULL handling logic.